# Scala, compiler error when passing a function parameter to an implicit converted class

Tags: scala

```
class RichCollection[T](underlying: List[T]) {
  def zip[A](fn: T => A): List[(T,A)] = underlying.map(i => (i, fn(i)))
}
implicit def collectionToRichCollection[T](collection: List[T]) = new RichCollection(collection)

val list = List("a", "bb", "ccc")
def fn(str: String) = str.length
list.zip(fn)
```

this last line fails with:

```
missing arguments for method fn
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
```

it actually works by modifying the code as proposed by the compiler:

```
list.zip(fn(_))
```

my question here is why I need to use the `(_)` there, and why it works without it in these two cases:

```
collectionToRichCollection(list).zip(fn)
new RichCollection(list).zip(fn)
```

Comment: Probably two implicits would be two confusing. ;-) Joke aside `fn` is not a function, just a method. Which might be overloaded.

Comment: You are aware that `List` already has a `zip` method? That probably makes your call ambiguous - if you rename your pimped method to something different, I suspect you'll be able to use it without the `_`. In some technical sense you always need an underscore whenever you want to treat a method as a function, but if the compiler knows that the value in that position needs to be of function type then it will allow you to omit it.

Comment: yes, i see that the code above works if renaming zip to zip2. so the problem is that there was too much magic, right? implicit class conversion, implicit conversion from method to function, and another method with the same name. please write down your previous  comment as a stackoverflow answer, so that i can accept it.